# Enterprise WSDL- Fetch only login method from WSDL

Tags: login, enterprise-wsdl

I'm working on SOAP API.I have successfully downloaded the Enterprise WSDL of my Org and i have imported it in SOAP UI tool to test it.I have one requirement wherein i need to provide only login() method of Enterprise WSDL to my client.I was thinking to modify the WSDL XML to  keep only the lines which are required for login() method and remove other lines which i don't require.Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and will make the WSDL easier for your client to understand and result in them having to generate way less code. Another approach would be to give them the Partner WSDL instead that also has a login operation but is 8k lines long rather than the 30k lines long Enterprise WSDL.

Comment: Thanks @Keith.Since Enterprise WSDL is huge i'm finding it tough to trim it.Do you have any sample WSDL which has only login() method, so that i can use it for reference.

Comment: @Ashish Sorry I don't.

Comment: No problem.Thanks@Keith.